# If a function $f:X\to X$ maps Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences then is $f$ uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences, uniform-continuity

> Let $X$ be an incomplete metric space. Does there exist examples of  continuous function $f:X\to X$ which map Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences but  is not  uniformly continuous ?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but if the claim is false in $\mathbb{R}$ then why do you expect it to hold in a general metric space?

Comment: If it is clearly false in $\mathbb R$, why do you think you can prove it in general metric spaces?

Comment: I'm also not seeing how this is clearly false in $\Bbb R$. Did you mean to write the opposite?

Comment: There are continuous functions on $\mathbb R$ which is not uniformly continuous @ElliotG ($\mathbb R$ is complete so Cauchy sequence must converges)

Comment: @Elliot G: A continuous function $f(x)$ on $\mathbb{R}$ can fail to be uniformly continuous by growing too quickly as $x\to\infty$, but Cauchy sequences won't detect this because they are bounded.

Comment: I see. This is my problem with trying to picture things visually I guess

Comment: @carmichael561 I read the question as "How does one prove _the fact that the claim is false_ in general metric spaces?" But fair point that clearer language would be helpful.

Comment: If $X$ is compact, then any continuous function is uniformly continuous. You need to elaborate the question a little to say what it is that you are looking for.

Comment: Question edited @carmichael561;@copper.hat@ John Ma @Elliot

Comment: $f : \mathbb Q\to \mathbb Q$, $f(x) = x^2$ is an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that Cauchy-continuity implies continuity. (We may assume WLOG that $X$ is complete; else we consider the completion of $X$.) For if $x_n\to x$ in $X$, then $\{x_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence, so given that $f$ is Cauchy-continuous, $\{f(x_n)\}$ is a Cauchy sequence and thus $f(x_n)\to f(x)$.

Now, if $X$ is totally bounded, then Cauchy-continuity implies uniform continuity. This follows from a metric space being compact iff it is complete and totally bounded, and the equivalence of continuity and uniform continuity in compact metric spaces.